# Malloc Fails when records are increased

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am using malloc in my code for memory allocation like below:

```
    a*aobj= malloc(sizeof(a)* (unsigned long) n*n);


 if(aobj== NULL){
 printf("Error. Allocation was unsuccessful. \n");
return 1;


}
```

a is a struct storing the result of three tables.When I am running for n>30000 records, it fails and gives the provided error message. Even after type casting, its not working. How can i modify to run it for more records?

Comment: What is the type of `n`?

Comment: "gives the provided error message." there is no error message in your question. [mcve] or it didn't happen.

Comment: @StoryTeller n refers to number of records here. It fails to allocate memory and return NULL when i am running it for n>30000.

Comment: I didn't ask what value `n` holds, I asked its data type. Please go over the [mcve] description again

Comment: @Swordfish My apologies. I mean it returns NULL and prints the message given in the if condition.>"Error. Allocation was unsuccessful";

Comment: `malloc` fails when you are low on memory.   If you don't have enough memory, you either need to change your hardware (ie, install more ram) or  lower your requirements.

Comment: 30,000² is a large number and depending on the size of `a`, the system may not be able to provide that much memory as contiguous chunk. (If `sizeof(a) == 4`, the number of allocated bytes goes beyond the 4GB limit.)

Comment: @StoryTeller `long int n;` i am giving it like this

Comment: Wow! How much memory do you have on your system? As noted, `30000 * 30000 = 900000000-bytes` (that's roughly a Gig per-`aobj`) and that's before you multiply by `sizeof(a)`.

Comment: You have tagged this as a C, pointers, and malloc question. It is not. It is clear, your system will not give you as much memory as you are asking for. There is no problem with C, pointers, or malloc. The problem is your system and, potentially, system configuration, such as process limits or defaults set by the system manager. To get any further answer, you must provide information about the system, and the size of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your struct has a size of 16 bytes, then you're trying to allocate:

*16 × 30000 × 30000 bytes = 14,400,000,000 bytes = 14.4 GBytes*

That's probably more than your computer has main memory available. So it fails because you're trying to allocate a too big chunk of memory.

Comment: I agree with your point.It will fail if code is running on local machine but I am running it on a cluster and that provides enough memory. I am not able to understand why its failing there.

Comment: Process sizes are not limited by the amount of main memory in the system. Virtual addressing enables process memory up to the virtual address space size, supported by swapping to disk or other storage.

Comment: @Nancy: The total memory in your cluster is not the determining factor in how much memory the system will give your process.

Comment: @Nancy: Can you provide information about the system you're using: hardware configuration, operating system, what you mean by "cluster" etc.?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Good point. Changes that the system will let you allocate 14 GBytes of memory are small though. Maybe all that's missing is some `ulimit` command to raise the size.